# Need to add abbreviations of the states printed in the center of each state of australia

Tags: r

Hi I have this R script that shows Australia map with state boundaries and I need to add abbreviated state names in the middle of each state. Any idea how to do that?

```
library(RColorBrewer)
```

`aus_b1 <- getData(name = "GADM", country = "Australia", level = 1)`

```
nrow(tidy(aus_b1))
aus_b1 <- tidy(ms_simplify(aus_b1))
nrow(aus_b1)
head(aus_b1)

aussie <- ggplot(data = aus_b1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
geom_polygon(aes(fill = id)) + 
coord_quickmap() + theme_map() +
guides(fill = F) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "BrBG"))

aussie
```